# How to remove dynamically added widgets in Python Kivy

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy, widget, kivy-language

can you please help solve an issue with Python Kivy.
I need to create a program where I want to create widgets (labels, buttons, text inputs) based on whatever is written **num_of_functions** list. Although I succeed in creating the widgets, removing them is a bigger challenge. No matter what I try I can't remove the buttons that have been created.

py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_file('random_button_adding.kv')

num_of_buttons = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

class Start(Screen):

    def add_buttons(self):
        for i in num_of_buttons:
            new_btn = Button(text=i)
            new_label = Label(text=i)
            new_text = TextInput(text=i)
            self.ids.grid_id_1.add_widget(new_btn)
            self.ids.grid_id_1.add_widget(new_label)
            self.ids.grid_id_1.add_widget(new_text)

    def remove_widgets(self, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        print(kwargs)
        self.ids.grid.remove_widget(self.ids.grid)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

kivy file:

```
<Start>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_id
            cols: 4
            size_hint: 1, 0.25
            Button:
                text: 'Add Buttons'
                on_press: root.add_buttons()
            Button:
                text: 'Remove Buttons'
                on_press: root.remove_widget(root.ids.grid_id_1)
            Button:
                id: btn3
                text: 'self removable buttons'
                on_press:
            Button:
                id: btn1
                text:'removable'

        GridLayout:
            id: grid_id_1
            cols: 3
```

[Actual program with the dynamic widgets within a red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq0JM.png)

So my question is how do I make the **remove_buttons** function work in way it removes the widgets within the red rectangle and also how can I create and add a unique ID to each of the created widget?

Thank you for your help
Kind regards, Daniel.

Comment: Did you get any error as the id `grid` in your `kvlang` is missing ?

Comment: Not sure if it helps : for getting list of child widgets from a parent widget , use `<widget instance>.children` ; for removing a widget , use `<parent widget instance>.remove_widget( <child widget instance> )` ; [Kivy Docs Reference](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html)